# Coin change. Dynamic programming

Tags: dynamic-programming, coin-change

I've found this algorithm online and it works, but I don't know why. Even though there is a video explaining it.

Here is the code:

```
public int numberOfSolutionsOnSpace(int total, int arr[]){

    int temp[] = new int[total+1];

    temp[0] = 1;
    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        for(int j=1; j <= total ; j++){
            if(j >= arr[i]){
                temp[j] += temp[j-arr[i]];
            }
        }
    }
    return temp[total];
}
```

Explanation:  [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fgjrs570YE&t=2s)

Could you please help me understand WHY this algorithm works? To be exact I don't understand why do we have to "go back n steps and add" ( 2:30 on the video )

Comment: StackOverflow is for specific questions about code problems; consider asking this instead on [the Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll post it there too :)